# Django retrieving JSON key/value from JSON string in textfield

Tags: python, json, django

I'm currently working on an app for logging changes to model fields. The changes are logged as a JSON string `{"field": field.name, "old_value": old_value, "new_value": new_value}` in a `textfield`.

How can I get specific keys/values of the JSON string? Current code:

**views.py**

```
def userChangelog(request, pk):

    user = User.objects.get(pk = pk)
    changelogs = ChangeLog.objects.filter(user_id = pk)

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'changelogs': changelogs,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/backend/user/user_changelog.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% for changelog in changelogs %}
    <p>1. {{ changelog.user }}</p>
    <p>2. {{ changelog.changes }}</p>
    <p>3. {{ changelog.date_of_change }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Ideally, I would like to do `<p>2. {{ changelog.changes.field }} changed from {{ changelog.changes.old_value }} to {{ changelog.changes.new_value }}</p>`, but can't seem to figure out how to translate only part of the query to `json.loads`, and display it in the template.

**Edit - ChangeLog model**

```
class ChangeLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'changed_by', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, models.SET_NULL, verbose_name = _('content type'), blank = True, null = True,)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    changes = models.TextField(_('changes'), blank = True)
    date_of_change = models.DateTimeField(_('change time'), default = timezone.now, editable = False,)

    objects = ChangeLogManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Change log entry')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Change log entries')

    def change_message(request, obj, old_instance):

        new_instance = obj.objects.get(pk = old_instance.pk)

        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(new_instance)

        for field in obj._meta.get_fields():
            if isinstance(field, models.ManyToOneRel):
                continue

            old_value = getattr(old_instance, field.name)
            new_value = getattr(new_instance, field.name)

            if old_value != new_value:
                change_message = json.dumps({"field": field.name, "old_value": old_value, "new_value": new_value})

                ChangeLog.objects.log_update(
                    user = request,
                    content_type = ct,
                    content_object = new_instance,
                    object_id = new_instance.pk,
                    changes = change_message,
                    date_of_change = timezone.now()
                )
```

Comment: The `ChangeLog` model - how is the `changes` field defined? There are plenty of solutions for JSON model fields

Comment: check out Django simple history: https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history

Comment: @gregory not interested in using a third party package as it does not fulfill my need. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Are you using postgres as your DB backend?

Comment: No, MySQL. Will try your answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to use a third party package. You could add a property to your `ChangeLog` model that parses and returns the changes JSON. [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) is useful as it stops you parsing the changes on every access

```
@cached_property
def changes_dict(self):
    return json.loads(self.changes)
```

Than you can use it in your template

```
{% for changelog in changelogs %}
    <p>1. {{ changelog.user }}</p>
    <p>2. {{ changelog.changes_dict.field }}</p>
    <p>2. {{ changelog.changes_dict.old_value }}</p>
    <p>2. {{ changelog.changes_dict.new_value }}</p>
    <p>3. {{ changelog.date_of_change }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```